# Symfony3 - SwiftMailer : non-existent parameter "mailer_encryption"

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

*My App in Symfony 3.2.4 and PHP 5.6.28*

Everything is up to date :
My SwiftMailer version :

> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.5.4)

When I read the official doc it's written that I can add parameters for SwiftMailer like this :

*config.yml*

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    encryption: "%mailer_encryption%"
    port:    "%mailer_port%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
    logging: true
```

*parameters.yml*

```
parameters:
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: BASE
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_host: smtp-relay._.com
    mailer_port: 587
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_encryption: tls
    mailer_user: -
    mailer_password: -
    secret: -
```

But when I run a "composer update" I always get the same error :

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
>   You have requested a non-existent parameter "mailer_encryption"

I have to comment "encryption" and "port" in config.yml and do a "composer update" again.

It's the normal behavior of SwiftMailer Bundle ? Can someone help me ?

I'm using FOSuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it a week ago like this :

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    encryption: tls
    port:    587
    spool:     { type: memory }
    logging: true
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone encounters this problem again it is because on update, composer looks at `parameters.yml.dist` which is being used as a template and if you have parameters in `parameters.yml` which are not present in the template they will get removed.

so in `parameters.yml.dist` you will have to add the field:

```
paremeters:
    ....
    mailer_transport:  smtp
    mailer_host:       127.0.0.1
    mailer_encryption: ~ (<!-- this line was added -->)
    mailer_user:       ~
    mailer_password:   ~
    ...
```

then you can add the value in `parameters.yml` like you did before and use it in `config.yml`

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:  "%mailer_transport%"
    host:       "%mailer_host%"
    username:   "%mailer_user%"
    password:   "%mailer_password%"
    encryption: "%mailer_encryption%"  (<!-- like this -->)
    port:       587    
    spool:      { type: memory }
    logging:    true
```

Same thing applies for the port